# Splitting trees on exponential loss function

Tags: cart, loss-functions

How are the regions determined in classification trees where in the exponential loss function is the splitting criterion? I know the constant we estimate for a region given this splitting criterion, but how are splits determined?

Are they determined by simple Gini Index / Misclassification error / Cross Entropy?

Comment: Are you saying the trees themselves are attempting to minimize the exponential loss greedily?

Comment: Well , yes . Actually my question arises from boosting trees. Dont they also use weighted exponentials for greedy splitting? Like in real adaboost for trees?

Comment: That's what I suspected you were getting at.  No, gradient boosting always uses trees that minimize squared error.  The trees are fit to the gradient of the loss, in your case the exponential loss.  The trees themselves are *not* fit to minimize the exponential loss.

Comment: @MatthewDrury , Yes I understand now. As I studied gradient boosting,things became more clear.